# Auth cookie dissapears after login over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have application written in asp.net MVC (NetFramework 4.7.2).

When I enter my credential and click Login button

1. POST to login page return 302 (with auth cookie)
2. REDIRECT to action returning dashboard (with auth cookie)
3. Everything works over HTTP, I can use my application.

But over HTTPS after dashboard is loaded auth cookie dissapears (there is no code on JS, maybe browser do it). Cookie has enabled flags HttpOnly and Secure. I use the newest Chrome to browser my app.

It's probably related with console error

> Clear-Site-Data" header on '': Unrecognized type "*"

I don't why it is added, I never have such header in code. Is it possible to browser do it?

Comment: If the browser drops the cookie it will usually write a message to the dev console about why it is dropping it. Do you see anything in the browser's console?

Comment: I see errors in console when css and js are downloaded
"Clear-Site-Data" header on '<URL>':   Unrecognized type "execution context"
"Clear-Site-Data" header on '<URL>':   Unrecognized type "*"

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski thanks, good point. I've updated my post, but I still don't know reason why header is added

Comment: It's a standard header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data The question is why is the backend sending that header and why only on HTTPS? The dropped cookie might be because of this.

Comment: Somebody set it on IIS in Response Header :/ Remove it resolve problem.
@MichalTrojanowski Thanks for hint. If you write it as answer I'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the browser drops the cookie it will usually write a message to the dev console about why it is dropping it. Most browsers are very specific about the reason for dropping cookies.

In your case, there seems like the response contains this header: `Clear-Site-Data`. It's a standard header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data The backend must be returning this header for some reason. Then the browser correctly drops the cookie as instructed.

It's interesting though, why the browser complains about the asterisk value. According to the docs this is one of allowed values for this header.